# Como voltar para a página do formulário ao enviar mensagem?

Tags: php, html

Depois de enviar a mensagem aparece o alert, mas o navegador não volta pro contact.html (formulário).

Depois eu gostaria de saber se consigo criar um estilo pra esse alerta também.

enviar.php

```
// ENVIO DO EMAIL
$enviado = $mail->Send();
// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();

// verifica se enviou corretamente
if ( $enviado ) {
    echo "<script>
        alert('Pedido enviado!');
    </script>";
}
else {
    echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
    echo "<b>Detalhes do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
header('Refresh: 10; Location: contact.html');
```

Comment: coloque o conteúdo de `contact.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem duas alternativas, criar um IF e ELSE para que volte a página que você quer, ou criar um código em JavaScript para a página nem redirecionar a medida que o usuário dá submit.

1ª alternativa

```
// ENVIO DO EMAIL
$enviado = $mail->Send();

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();



// verifica se enviou corretamente
if ($enviado) {
    echo "<script>alert('Pedido enviado!');location.href='contact.html';</script>";
}
else {
    echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
    echo "<b>Detalhes do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    echo "<script>location.href='contact.html';
}
```

2ª alternativa caso sejam enviados dados através de um botão de `type="submit"`

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ajax').submit(function(){

            var dados = $(this).serialize();


            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "enviar.php",
                    data: dados,
                    success: function( data )
                    {
                            alert( data );
                    }
            });

            return false;
    });
});
```

mas no seu form terá que adicionar uma class para dar certo e ficaria meio que assim

```
<form action=''method='' class='ajax'>
```

Comment: Conseguiu @AlanVieira

Comment: Ótima resposta @AlanVieira

Comment: obrigado @avsinacio a resposta é minha

Comment: Ops...  ótima solução @Victor

Answer (score 1):

Basta você configurar um header location, a mensagem será exibida em javascript, posterior ao clique (seja em cancelar ou em OK), ele retorná ao contact.html, conforme desejado.

```
// ENVIO DO EMAIL
$enviado = $mail->Send();
// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();



// verifica se enviou corretamente
    if ( $enviado ) {

        echo "<script>
            if(confirm("Ok, enviado com sucesso")){
                  <?php header("Location: contact.html"); ?>
            }
        </script>";

    }
    else {
        echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
        echo "<b>Detalhes do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Eu cheguei a fazer dessa forma, mas a mensagem é enviada e o alerta não aparece.

Comment: @AlanVieira tente da forma que indiquei na minha resposta, aqui deu certo a 1ª alternativa atendeu seu caso ?

Comment: Não entendi pra que negativar a resposta...

Comment: foi sem querer a intenção era positivar, edite ela para eu retirar o negativo e positivar

Comment: Você pode fazer dessa forma, que eu editei a questão :)

Comment: pronto @AndréBaill manda um positivo para mim também rsrsrs

Comment: @Victor a solução primeira foi boa, achei interessante também :D

Comment: obrigado, a sua também, é a programação demonstrando mais uma vez que diversas lógicas geram mesmo resultado e performance